# Login Based on URL Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

Is it possible to prompt a log in to authenticate based on a querystring value?

I have a site requiring authentication, except in the case when a token is passed in the querystring. A requirement is that the token users already log in to a thick client and they must only log in once. From the client they click a generated link with a token in query string to open the web page. The site must also be available to non-thick client users by opening directly in browser and authenticating via prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't authenticate via the query string.  Force a login and let the user select a context to run under.

Comment: Alas, my hand is forced by the customer. We would be getting an encrypted key in the query string generated from a third party app which we would use to validate against their system so they aren't prompted for log in.

Comment: That's not logging in or impersonating, that is passing a token to a SSO process.

Comment: And if the key is not in the querystring, we must prompt a log in. So my question remains.

Comment: You should elaborate what you are trying to do in the question.  It will probably get closed being so vague.

Comment: +1: Don't know why this was downvoted, so I've taken corrective measures.

Comment: +1 Also, your original question states you are passing Login=true in the query string, which is not what your responses here indicate. Passing a token in a query string is completely different than passing login=true. So, please update your original question with what is actually going to happen.

Comment: Took out my query string example. So the question still stands, regardless of a token/query string use.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

on page load you can check for the `login=`.

Do your check with the third party app to see if the token is correct. Afther that:

```
    Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
    Response.Redirect("samepage.aspx");
```